# Connecting Small business network to Azure Site to Site VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, azure

Would like to have connectivity between azure virtual machines and on LAN users.

My current network has a Cisco ISA550 connected to the WAN (one Ethernet cable into the office the fiber transceiver is on a different floor)and any public servers can be one-to one NAT-ed to have a public and private IP.

What is the best way to get a reliable connection. Between end users and the cloud?  I want to know the preferred on site endpoint.

Do the azure vm's have to have a local ip in the LAN subnet? (Right now 10.10.0.0/20 or 255.255.240.0 to give room if this is the case).

If in purchased an asa550 would I put it behind or in front of the isa550. Would it be ahead or peer with the users switches?

**What is the best way to get a reliable connection. Between end users and the cloud servers?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be setup using the Cisco ISA550 Directly

```
LAN  10.10.1.0 Subnet 255.255.255.0
Azure  10.10.2.0 Subnet 255.255.255.0
```

Blog Post explains in detail.

http://www.markgreenway.net/setting-up-azure-site-to-site-with-small-business-router/

Comment: I presume you didn't intend to link to a non-existant page.

Comment: Oh forgot the blog post is delayed publish

Answer (score 0):

Hi Azure does not support VPN endpoint behind a router ( SOurce Nat )

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/19eb5ac0-5fb1-4afa-8081-5afc32cb04fd/is-nat-supported-within-an-ipsec-vpn-connection?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork

So I would say on the front.

But It will actually works it is just that Azure support will lecture you and say "don't do that.." ( I did it with my Ubiquity and it is working for more than 6 months ):

https://mouradcloud.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/blog/blog/2017/11/22/part-1-step-connecting-vpn/